# Which characters to quote is shell script assignment?

Tags: escaping, variable-assignment, sh, quoting

I can't assign

```
RED5_HOME=/opt/red5-1.0.0
```

since variable appears to empty.

Probably some characters in variable value are to backslashed. Where to get complete list of characters which should be backslashed in shell script assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This list seems to be the list you want http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

However, your string should work just fine. I don't think any of those symbols have any special meaning in sh in this context. Try surrounding the the string with single quotes ('), that escapes all special characters. Like this

```
RED5_HOME='/opt/red5-1.0.0'
```